# $SU(2)$ is a covering space of $SO(3)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-groups

The method of topology is very clear.Then there's a question asking to use adjoint representation of lie group $SU(2)$ $(\operatorname{adj}:SU(2)\to GL(su(2)))$to prove this. I can't solve this .

Comment: What do you mean by "the method of topology"? What have you tried? What do you know about the relationship between covering spaces and Lie groups?

Comment: Dear henry, The group $SU(2)$ acts on its Lie algebra via the adjoint rep'n (more concretely, by conjugation).  This Lie algebra is 3-dimensional, and so this gives a representation of $SU(2)$ by $3\times 3$ matrices.  Now check that these matrices lie in $SO(3)$ (perhaps by finiding a quadratic form on the Lie algebra $su(2)$ that this action preserves).  Regards,